# Поддержка форка

Tags: git, github

Лежит на гитхабе одна опенсорсная библиотека, и есть в ней такой код

```c
sockfd = (int)socket(addr->ai_family, addr->ai_socktype, addr->ai_protocol);
```

Понятно, что под Win64 это чудо работать не будет. Проблема еще и в том, что использование 32-х битного `sockfd` размазано по всей библиотеке, включая экспортные функции.

Баг-репорт я написал, но, честно говоря, надежды на его исправление мало.

Я могу сделать форк этой библиотеки и самому все исправить.

Вопрос, смогу ли я потом вливать в мой форк все изменения, которые происходят в основной ветке или он окажется абсолютно неподдерживаемым?

Comment: Не вижу причины, чтобы в Win64 не будет работать. Int он и в Африке int.

Comment: @AlexGlebe потому, что функция `socket()` возвращает тип `SOCKET`, который под Win64 имеет размер 64 бита

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно сможете. [Вот тут](https://help.github.com/en/articles/syncing-a-fork) можно почитать на английском

Если в кратце, то сначала настраиваете `upstream`:

```
$ remote add upstream https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git
```

А потом можно будет вливать себе все изменения из оригинала:

```
$ git fetch upstream
$ git merge upstream/master
```